# Fastlane generated plist file with wrong provisionprofile

Tags: ios, archive, fastlane

I want to export appstore ipa

Use match

```
match(type: "appstore", readonly: true)
```

I set gym export_options

```
gym(
    scheme: "MyApp",
    output_name: "MyApp.ipa",
    export_method: "app-store",
    export_options: {
        compileBitcode: false,
        provisioningProfiles: {
            "com.my.bundleID" => "DIS_Provision",
        }
    },
    include_symbols: true,
    include_bitcode: false
)
```

before archive, I got message below

```
Detected provisioning profile mapping: {:"com.my.bundleID"=>"DEV_Provision"}
```

and when archive succeed, fastlane generate plist, I got plist

```
{
    "compileBitcode": false,
    "provisioningProfiles": {
        "com.my.bundleID" => "DEV_Provision"
    },
    "method": "app-store",
    "uploadSymbols": true,
    "uploadBitcode": false,
    "signingStyle": "manual"
}
```

Why fastlane detected the wrong ProvisionProfile?

Comment: why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: I set export_options with DIS profile, but fastlane generated with DEV profile

Comment: Did you set correct scheme and configuration?
scheme: "xxx", configuration: "Release"

Comment: can you add your full gym file?

Comment: Full gym added.

Comment: The only thing I can think that can work. is to set configuration: "release" in there.

Comment: Are you sure that you need to use match and also set the provisioning profiles like this? I think this doesn't make so much sense.

Comment: maybe setting the configuration and using match is enough. or don't use match or set configuration and only set the profiles. one or the other. I guess match is getting the first profile that match and ignores the profiles setting there since configuration is not set.

Comment: My configuration is set to release and remove export_options, but not working

Answer (score 3):

This might be late but I found a solution since I also had the same issue. You just have to set skip_profile_detection to true in gym. I just added `skip_profile_detection(true)` to my gymfile and it worked.

Comment: fantastic. this solved the issue for me. even though I'm specifying provisioning profiles it's still autodetecting?! what is that about? thanks a lot 

Answer (score 0):

i get a similar problem .

try to check the xcode buildsetting 'PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).